# Error Running 'nx run graph:serve' Command for Node.js GraphQL App - Function Invocation Issue

Tags: node.js, nx-monorepo

I have been trying to setup my project for last 2 days but I am getting error.
I have attached error screenshot.

I am trying to run graph app which is nodejs project using graphql.

Thanks in advance.[image: Screenshot of error]

removed package-lock.json file and node_modules and reinstall node_modules but not working.